# Listing All tags - and linking them to list of entries with that tag

Tags: entries, tags

I have a blog, and in the sidebar I have listed all tags in use. I would like to link each tag - when you click it I want to link to a page that lists all the blog entries which have that tag applied to them. Cant find this in the docs.. would someone mind helping? Here is my code so far:

```
<div class="tagblock">
    {% set entries = craft.entries.section('blog').limit(null) %}
         {% for tag in craft.tags %}
           <div class="tag"><a href="{{ url('blog-page/'~tag.id) }}">{{ tag.title }}</a></div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

MY RESULTS: This code is linking to for example mysite.com/blog-page/88 - and giving me a page not found. I have a template blog-page and the path is correct as the page loads if you remove the tag-id off the end.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You don't have a setting in Craft to make Tags have their own pages automatically. So what you have to do instead, is to set up a [dynamic route](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes) in Settings → Routes. Create a new route which routes these URIs: blog/tags/[slug] (drag the slug token into the URI field) to a template blog/_tags.html.

In your blog/_tags.html template you will now have a slug variable available, but you still need to query for the tag model / entry models.

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.slug(slug).first() %}
{% if not tag %}{% exit 404 %}{% endif %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('blog').relatedTo(tag).limit(null) %}

<h2>{{ tag.title }}</h2>

{% for entry in entries %}
{% endfor %}
```

I'd also modify the tag listing to only show tags that are actually related to an entry, and use the tags' (undocumented) slug property for SEO purposes:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('blog').limit(null) %}
{% set tags = craft.tags.relatedTo(entries).limit(null) %}

{% for tag in tags %}
    <a href="{{ url('blog/tags/'~tag.slug) }}">{{ tag.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```